# FunGen C dependencies?

Tags: c, haskell, ghc

I have completed my game (mostly for a demo) using haskell with FunGen. I now have my game.exe to run it on Windows. The thing is running on some machines. Some of them wont open my game, since they freeze the game window before the game can be played.

I made a quite strange hipothesis. Machines of video game players will run my game, not 100% sure, but so far i cant deny it.
So i infer there may be some C libraries that video games use to install in a computer in order to run them.

is there some implicit dependency that FunGen needs?

Comment: I don't know anything of FunGen, but it's hackage page (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FunGEn) says "Dependencies: base (4.*), GLUT, haskell98, OpenGL, random". Do you have GLUT and OpenGL installed on those PCs?

Comment: Bundle all your libraries and use [bamse](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bamse) to make an installer.